# Negate boost is_directory in std algorithm

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, negate

```
boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, begin(directory);

auto num_of_files=std::count_if(begin, end, 
        std::not1(boost::filesystem::is_directory)));
```

I am trying to negate the function is_directory on the above directory iterator but am hitting  a brick wall. I have tried specifying the template for `not1` as `bool(*)(const boost::filesystem::path&)` and tried static casting the function both without success.

I know I can resort to a lamdba but this is cleaner if it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::not1` needs a function object as its argument. This function object can be obtained with `std::ptr_fun`, so this should work:

```
auto num_of_files=std::count_if(begin, end, 
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun((bool(*)(const boost::filesystem::path&))boost::filesystem::is_directory)));
```

(the number of parentheses is probably incorrect). BTW, you need the cast because `is_directory` is an overloaded function.

However, since you tag you question c++11, you could use lambdas:

```
auto num_of_files=std::count_if(begin, end, [](const boost::filesystem::path& p) { return !boost::filesystem::is_directory(p); });
```

Comment: Ah, I am some 30 seconds late :)

Comment: Worked a charm I prefer this syntax it reads better to me:    ...std::ptr_fun<const boost::filesystem::path &, bool>(boost::filesystem::is_directory)...

Comment: @111111, you are insane, or possibly a robot.  I mean to say that as kindly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

not1 accepts an instance of functor class, which should be an [Adaptable Predicate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AdaptablePredicate.html) (i.e. with typedefs for return value etc.), while you are trying to feed it with a function pointer. So you need to wrap it in a functor and [ptr_fun](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/ptr_fun/) might help.
Perhaps this would work (assume using namespace std; using namespace boost;):

```
auto num_of_files=count_if(begin, end, not1(ptr_fun(filesystem::is_directory)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ptr_fun,

this rather elaborate illustration should print `1` three times: (see also http://ideone.com/C5HTR)

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool pred(const std::string& s)
{
    return s.size() % 2;
}

int main()
{
    std::string data[] = { "hello", "world!" };

    std::cout << std::count_if(data, data+2, 
            pred) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::count_if(data, data+2, 
            std::ptr_fun(pred) ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::count_if(data, data+2, 
            std::not1(std::ptr_fun(pred))) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```